Why does HF Transformers run out of (GPU) memory frequently, when the same model can run fine in Ollama?
I can imagine Python taking more resources in general, but even with 10GB of GPU RAM, I'm unable to run inference using HF Transformers for small models like Phi3 4K.
Looking for qualitative and quantitative insights. Can someone touch on how much resources does the model take, vs. pytorch, vs. HF Transformers code.
The program I'm using is a quite simple inference program shown below.
(Note I tried changeing torch_dtype to 16-bit too as shown in the code)
import sys
import torch

from transformers import AutoModelForCausalLM, AutoTokenizer

model_name = "microsoft/Phi-3-mini-4k-instruct"

model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(model_name, trust_remote_code=True, torch_dtype=torch.float16, device_map="cuda")
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name, trust_remote_code=True)

job_descr = sys.stdin.read()
input_ids = tokenizer(job_descr,  return_tensors="pt").input_ids.to("cuda")
outputs = model.generate(input_ids, do_sample=True, max_new_tokens=300)

print(tokenizer.decode(outputs[0], skip_special_tokens=True), "\n")

